# Segerror occures during mat reading until ostream is used

Tags: c++, opencv, segmentation-fault, iostream

I have two CV_32FC1 Mat `flow[0]` and `flow[1]` generated in this way

```
 95         cv::gpu::BroxOpticalFlow bof(alpha, gamma, scale_factor, inner_iteratoins, outter_iterations, solver_iterations);
 96         bof(gpuFrame[0], gpuFrame[1], gpuFlow[0], gpuFlow[1]);
 97
 98         cv::Mat flow[2];
 99         for(int i=0; i<2; ++i) {
100                 gpuFlow[i].download(flow[i]);
101         }
```

The segmentation error is occurred at line 117 only if both 115 and 116 lines are commented.

```
105         cv::Size flow_size = flow[0].size();
106
107         std::size_t vertices_count = flow_size.width * flow_size.height;
108
109         std::list< int > vertices;
110         for(int j=0; j<flow_size.height; ++j) {
111                 const double * x_flow = flow[0].ptr<double>(j);
112                 const double * y_flow = flow[1].ptr<double>(j);
113
114                 for(int i=0; i<flow_size.width; ++i, ++x_flow, ++y_flow) {
115                         //std::cout << i << ' ' << j << std::endl;
116                         //std::cout << "|" << std::endl;
117                         if(norm(*x_flow, *y_flow) > eps) {
118                                 vertices.push_back(i + j*flow_size.width);
119                         }
120                 }
121         }
```

If the code invoked from a command line, nothing is returned. However, segfault error code is returned, when the program is executed in gdb. When either 115 or 116 is uncommented, everything is fine.

g++ version is 4.9.2. OpenCV 2.4.9 compiled with CUDA. c++11 flag is used.

Comment: Create a minimal example. Memory corruption can surface at any distance from where it is committed and random operations can sometimes hide it, so your bug can be anywhere.

Comment: Not enough information to provide anything but guesses. For example, if this program is multithreaded this sounds like a race condition.

Comment: the reason why it does not happen if some lines are commented out sounds like either a timing difference  (multi-threading race condition) or a difference in memory allocation of your program (if you are unlucky segfaults don't occur because you accidentally access a memory position that belongs to your program although you instead wanted to access a different position.).

Comment: another possibility are uninitialized variables.

Comment: change const double * x_flow to const float * x_flow because CV_32F if float, not double. same for y_flow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CV_32FC1` is `float`, not `double`.

Change

```
const double * x_flow = flow[0].ptr<double>(j);
const double * y_flow = flow[1].ptr<double>(j);
```

to

```
const float * x_flow = flow[0].ptr<float>(j);
const float * y_flow = flow[1].ptr<float>(j);
```

interpreting float memory as double memory means that you are reading 2x the number of memory blocks for each pixel. Therefore you'll walk out of the image memory and get a segfault, if the next memory block does not belong to your program.

You're accessing the elements in line `117` on `*x_flow, *y_flow`.

If you don't get a segfault, then you're "accidentally" accessing memory of your own program, but anyways you don't read the values that you wanted to read from the beginning.

Comment: That is. when I print anything, a some memory is allocated, which is being accessed by `*x_flow, *y_flow` ?

Comment: maybe yes, maybe no... I'm not sure. But if you uncomment/comment the compiler might or might not order your application memory differently. So maybe just the memory ordering was chosen differently. At least that's my intuition, I'm not that deep in compiler stuff that I could guarantee correctness....

Comment: std::cout << "Thank you"